# After giving a code chunk with crosstalk and plotly combo. I cannot export any html output properly

Tags: r, r-markdown, plotly

I have to make a bar chart with a drop down filter menu on side in an Rmarkdown document. However the problem is that when I add it as an 'r chunk' I cannot export it out into a static html format.

The issue is that using R shiny is a workable method for me in at my work. So this the code I have so far:

```
library(crosstalk)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

iris_data <-
SharedData$new(iris, key = ~Species, group = "Select Specie")
bscols(
    filter_select("species", "Species", iris_data, ~Species, multiple = FALSE)
  ,

plot_ly(iris_data, x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Petal.Length, type = 'bar', name = ~Species, color= ~Species, text = ~ Sepal.Width) %>% layout(iris_data, barmode = 'stack'))
```

On the other hand when I knit the document into a html the preview only shows the top title parts then freezes out, and the html file crashes when I try to open it with firefox. Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: How big is your dataset (`Weeks_and_countries`)?

Comment: Hi! It's relatively average: 767 rows and 5 cols.

Comment: Hmm, large datasets can make crosstalk freeze in regular HTML, but that doesn't seem to be an issue here.  Can you edit your post into a minimal, reproducible example -- including any Rmd headers?

Comment: Hi! I just edited it. Thank you for your patience. However when I change the source to "iris" it works just fine without any problems.